# implementation of a method looking like 2 methods put together

Tags: objective-c

I don't understand the implementation of the method in CODE 1.

```
//CODE 1
@implementation Tom
- (void)alice:(Alice*)alice
  didReceiveData:(Data*)data {
  //...
}
@end
```

It seems to me that I have 2 methods like:

```
- (out1)method1:in1
method2:in2{
//...
}
```

What is the meaning of this syntax?

The documentation says `didReceiveData` is called every time Tom receive data and on that occasion Tom receives a reference to Alice too.
So I would expect something like CODE 2.

```
//CODE 2
@implementation Tom
- (void)didReceiveData:(Data*)data,(Alice*)alice{
   //...
}
@end
```

What is the meaning of CODE 1?

Comment: Read how declare method with multiple args in Objective-C

Comment: See [Method Declarations Indicate the Messages an Object Can Receive](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH3-SW8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objective-C is based on C, and as such whitespace (space, tabs, newlines) does not have any meaning except separation of language elements for parsing and readability. Hence, you can use newlines in any place where you can also use a space.

```
- (void)alice:(Alice*)alice
  didReceiveData:(Data*)data {
  //...
}
```

can also be written as:

```
- (void)alice:(Alice*)alice didReceiveData:(Data*)data {
  //...
}
```

This last form lets you see the method name, which is: `alice:didReceiveData:`

Comment: @bluestone Yes, that is correct. In case you wonder about the now slightly odd format of a method call: It comes from the language Smalltalk, which was the hottest object-oriented language in the early 80s.

Comment: So alice and data are both input parameters?
But why alice is written in the middle of the method name?

This method is equivalent to
    - (void)alice:didReceiveData: (Alice*)alice (Data*)data {
    //...}
, where I put all input parameters after the name of the method?

Comment: No, the normal Objective-C (and Smalltalk) method format requires you to have the input parameters mixed in with the method name. And convention dictates the use camel-case as well to help with readability.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies!